# How to efficiently extract count of each item from huge dataset?

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, sqlite

The problem is following:

- Input: All articles from Wikipedia (33gb of text)
- Output: Count of each words skipgram (n-gram with maximum k skips) from Wikipedia in SQLite file.

Output table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [tokens] ([token] TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [count] INTEGER  NOT NULL
```

The naive approach is that for each skipgram we create a new record in table or increment counter in existing record:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO [tokens] VALUES (@token, COALESCE((SELECT count FROM [tokens] WHERE token=@token), 0) + 1)
```

The problem with this approach is that index is constantly updated and when database grows to several giga those updates are very slow. We can solve this by creating the "tokens" table without index and adding index at end of processing.

The problem is that the select statement `SELECT count FROM [tokens] WHERE token=@token` that has to scan the table is significantly reducing performance.

The best method I have found so far is following (I am using C#):

1. Create a `Dictionary<string,int>` in order to count tokens.
2. Add tokens to this dictionary till it gets too big to fit in the RAM.
3. Insert (not update) tokens from the dictionary to temporarily table without index. The table has following schema:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [temp] ([token] TEXT, [count] INTEGER)
   ```
4. If there are more tokens, clear the dictionary and go to step 2.
5. Copy tokens from temp table to tokens table:

   ```
   INSERT INTO [tokens] SELECT [token], SUM([count]) AS [count] FROM [temp] GROUP BY [token]
   ```

This method takes "only" 24 hours to process the dataset, but I believe that it is not the best approach because the step 5 takes 22 out of 24 hours.

Do you know an alternative approach that can solve this problem?

P.S. My application is single threaded and I make the above inserts in batches (100000 per batch) within transaction.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest creating of another table with the same definition, populating the table to a certain state, merging the results to the main one, purging the table and starting processing the next set of items.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not completely solves the slow index update problem it only makes those updates less frequent while each update take more time. After few merges the updates become relatively slow (ten minutes to merge 10 million records). And my dataset contains billions of tokens.

Comment: @user1096250, I would also look at the sqlite temporary files tuning (http://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ UNCOMMITTED`.  That means it is possible the counts could be slightly off, especially in a threaded enviornment where multiple are trying to insert/update at the same time.

Comment: Sorry that was for MS SQL I didn't notice you were using SQLITE

Answer (score 0):

If you have many gigs to spare....

I suggest that you do not count the tokens as you go, but rather add all the tokens into a single table and create an index that organizes the tokens.

```
CREATE TABLE tokens (token TEXT);
CREATE INDEX tokens_token ON tokens (token ASC);
```

then add all of the token one at a time...

```
INSERT INTO tokens VALUES ('Global Warming');
INSERT INTO tokens VALUES ('Global Cooling');
```

finally execute a `SELECT ... GROUP BY`

```
SELECT token, COUNT(0) token_count FROM tokens GROUP BY token
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I am currently use similar approach. I added it to my original question. Do you think that the index on my temporarily table can be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place to use a "counting bloom filter" to me.

It'd require two passes over your data, and it's a bit heuristic, but it should be fast.  Bloom filters allow set insertion and presence tests in constant time.  A counting bloom filter counts how many of a particular value have been found, as opposed to the usual bloom filter that only keeps track of presence/absence.

Comment: I cannot use a "counting bloom filter" because I need the possibility to query this table e.g. "select * from tokens where count>1000".